# How to update data(props) in a Navigation destination screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

**Ques:** Is there a way to update data(props) in a Navigate destination screen, if the state of Navigation Source screen is updated ?

lets say, I navigate from `ScreenA` to `ScreenB` and pass it Navigation props `data`

> ScreenA ➔ ScreenB

```
ScreenA {
   navigate('ScreenB', {data: this.state.data})

   someEvent(){
      this.setState({data: newData})
   }
}
```

While `ScreenB` is displayed, some event happened on `ScreenA`, and its `state.data` is updated. How `ScreenB` can get this updated data ?

---

I'll try to explain it further, with a detailed code sample :

There is a `PostInfo` class screen, that stores all the comments on a post, and renders a button.
When this button is clicked, screen navigates to `PostDetails` class screen. `PostInfo` class provides `allComments` and a callback function `replyCommentCB` as navigation props.

This `PostDetails` class then renders all the comments and a comment reply `textInputBox`.
When a user replies to a comment through this `textInputBox`, the callback function `replyCommentCB` is triggered and it updates the state in `PostInfo` class, by adding this new comment.

However, now i want this newly updated state of `allComments` to be reflected in the `PostDetails` Screen as well, so that this newly added comment can also be rendered.

```
class PostInfo {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            allComments = []
        }
    }

    replyCommentCB = (text) => {
        /* Update comment in DataBase first then update state */
        updatedAllComments = this.state.allComments
        updatedAllComments.push(text)
        this.setState ( {
            allComments : updatedAllComments
        })
    }

    onButtonPress = () => {
        this.navigation.navigate('PostDetails', {
          allComments   : this.state.allComments,
          replyCommentCB: this.replyCommentCB,
        }
      );
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Button title={"Show Comments"} onPress={this.onButtonPress}/>
        )
    }
}


class PostDetails {
    render() {
        let allComments    = this.props.navigation.getParam('allComments',[]);
        let replyCommentCB = this.props.navigation.getParam('replyCommentCB','');
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                /* Render "allComments" here */
                <TextInputBox onSubmit={replyCommentCB} />
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```

PS:

1. I do not want to use Redux etc state management.
2. If I put the `PostDetails` class in a Modal (instead of navigation.navigate) it
   works OK. (when state is updated in PostInfo class, the props of `PostDetails` modal are also updated)

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself. All i needed to do is to return the updated data from the function callback.

```
class PostInfo {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state = {
            allComments = []
        }
    }

    replyCommentCB = (text) => {
        /* Update comment in DataBase first then update state */
        updatedAllComments = this.state.allComments
        updatedAllComments.push(text)
        this.setState ({ allComments : updatedAllComments })
        return updatedAllComments;  // return the data that you want to get updated in navigated screen
    }

    onButtonPress = () => {
        this.navigation.navigate('PostDetails', {
          allComments   : this.state.allComments,
          replyCommentCB: this.replyCommentCB,
        }
      );
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Button title={"Show Comments"} onPress={this.onButtonPress}/>
        )
    }
}


class PostDetails {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.replyCommentCB = this.props.navigation.getParam('replyCommentCB','');
        this.state = { allComments : this.props.navigation.getParam('allComments',[]) }
    }

    onReplyComment(text) {
        const updatedAllComments = this.replyCommentCB(text)
        this.setState({ allComments   : updatedAllComments })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                /* Render "this.state.allComments" here */
                <TextInputBox onSubmit={onReplyComment} />
            </ScrollView>
        )
    }
}
```